# c++ how to assign a default value to a template argument when instantiating the class

Tags: c++, string, templates, inheritance, char

I working on a set of inherited classes, the base is non template, protected constructors and purely virtual methods with no member variables: it serves as a declaration of what the actual inherited template class will and needs to contain.

In the inherited version it has only one template argument `size_t` as this is needed for setting the size of the stored character array so I need to have my class prefixed with `template<size_t fixed_size>`. It has two private members
one which will contain the size of the string passed in by anyone one of its valid constructors that must except a single parameter. So I was thinking of making this variable a `static const size_t` and for the other variable which is just a `char[]` will be set as being `[size_t + 1]`. What I would like to do is to have the member variable of the `static const size_t` be set not during instantiation itself, but when its constructor is called and the size would come from the length of the `char[]`, `char*` or `std::string.size()` that is passed in from one of its valid constructors. Also when I go to instantiate a class I don't want to do the following: `fixed_string<some value> myString( "hello" );` I would rather have it do this instead: `fixed_string myString( "hello" );` Here is what my classes currently look like:

```
#include <string>

// This base class does not contain any member variables 
// and no implementations of any constructor or function
// it serves as a definition to your interface as well as
// defining what methods must be implemented.
class fixed_string_base {
protected:
    // The types of constructors you want to implement
    explicit fixed_string_base( char words[] ) {};
    explicit fixed_string_base( const char* words ) {}
    explicit fixed_string_base( const std::string words ) {}    

    // The types of things you want to leave to default
    fixed_string_base() = default;
    fixed_string_base( fixed_string_base const& ) = default;
    fixed_string_base( fixed_string_base&& ) = default;
    fixed_string_base& operator=( fixed_string_base const& ) = default; 
    fixed_string_base& operator=( fixed_string_base&& ) = default;
    virtual ~fixed_string_base() = default;
public:
    // Put all of your pure virtual methods here that fixed_string must implement;
    virtual char* c_str() = 0;
};

// This is the actual class that inherits from its non
// templated declaration interface.
template<size_t fixed_size>
class fixed_string : public fixed_string_base {
private:
    static const size_t fixed_string_size_ = fixed_size + 1;
    char fixed_string_[ fixed_string_size_ ];

public:
    // Experimental not sure how to set the fixed_string_size_ from the size of the array passed in to the constructors
    explicit fixed_string( char words[] ) : fixed_string_size_( sizeof( words ) + 1 ) {
        fixed_string_ = words;
        fixed_string_[fixed_size] = '\0';
    }
    explicit fixed_string( const char* words ) : fixed_string_size_( sizeof( words ) + 1 ) {
        fixed_string_ = words;
        fixed_string_[fixed_size] = '\0';
    }
    explicit fixed_string( const std::string& words ) : fixed_string_size( words.size() + 1 ) {
        fixed_string_ = words.c_str();
        fixed_string_[fixed_size] = '\0';
    }

    virtual char* c_str() { return fixed_string_; }

    // Defaulted Constructors and Operators
    fixed_string( fixed_string const& ) = default;
    fixed_string( fixed_string&& ) = default;
    fixed_string& operator=( fixed_string const& ) = default;
    fixed_string& operator=( fixed_string&& ) = default;
    virtual ~fixed_string() = default;
};
```

When I try to compile these are the errors that I'm getting:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FileTester, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\filetester\filetester\main.cpp(71): error C2438: 'fixed_string_size_': cannot initialize static class data via constructor
1>  c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\filetester\filetester\main.cpp(71): note: while compiling class template member function 'fixed_string<5>::fixed_string(const char *)'
1>  c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\filetester\filetester\main.cpp(103): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'fixed_string<5>::fixed_string(const char *)' being compiled
1>  c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\filetester\filetester\main.cpp(103): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'fixed_string<5>' being compiled
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\filetester\filetester\main.cpp(72): error C3863: array type 'char [6]' is not assignable
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I kind of understand what the compiler errors are stating but I'm not sure about how to resolve them to finish implementing this class. Are there any newer features of the VS2015 CE compiler that are available that would help me here such as `auto` or maybe even some `lambda` techniques? I'm not sure what I'm overlooking. Any tips, suggestions or help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
template <std::size_t N>
fixed_string<N> make_fixed_string(const char(&s)[N])
{
    return fixed_string<N>(s);
}
```

So you can do

```
auto s = make_fixed_string("Hello");
```

I let you fix your constructors, as you have to do `strncpy`, as there is no copy of C-array.

Comment: Think that might work, but I'm trying to prevent having to allocate on the heap, and also once this is constructed the string is fixed and can't be modified, it'll only be able to return its value, and to compare to another fixed string if they are `==` or not.

Comment: I don't allocate (as you), and RVO and copy elision should probably occurs with decent compiler. And if you want the string to be `const`, you can still add `const`: `const auto s = make_fixed_string("Hello");`.

Comment: Well there may be times that I do want to allocate on the heap, but there are times I don't. So trying to write a handy class that will do this for me automatically. Basically a wrapper around a `const char[fixed_size]` that is set upon the values passed from the constructors. I didn't want to inherit from `std::string` either.`, but it is okay to accept an `std::string` as a valid parameter or input.